# AxiosError: Network Error in React Native on making api request to local backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, axios

```
Frontend

await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/admin/api/getcategories",{
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          }).then(result=>{
            console.log(result);
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log(err);
        })
```

```
Backend
```

const cors = require('cors');

```
app.use(cors());
```

Tried restarting the application, and with other api tried sending without headers, but nothing worked, also added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

for android
and
NSAllowsArbitraryLoads
for IOS

Comment: `http://localhost:8000` wont work with mobile device, it will moslty ping the device itself, instead try to find the ip address of your dev machine, open the port 8000 to public and use the link with the   `http://serverIP:800`

Answer (score -1):

Try to use ngrok (https://ngrok.com/) to make your local API public. It is free for developers